# django allauth email signup - custom logic

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am using django 1.10 and django-allauth for authentication on my website.

For email/password (i.e. non social) login, I want to be able to place code to check the email - so that I DISALLOW signup from certain well known spammy domains.

So I want to incorporate logic like this:

```
BANNED_DOMAINS = ('foobar.com', 'foo.biz', 'example.')

def email_has_banned_domain(email):
    found = False
    for x in BANNED_DOMAINS:
        if x in email:
            found = True
            break

    return found
```

How do I then, incorporate this simple function to the allautrh workflow, to prevent singups from banned domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to customize the allauth flow is by defining a custom [Adapter](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#creating-and-populating-user-instances). The documentation doesn't list all the hooks, but a look at the source code shows a [`clean_email()`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/cb4e47dd4a2480af35a54b8c944df25fb31f6491/allauth/account/adapter.py#L279) method that should do what you want.

> Validates an email value. You can hook into this if you want to (dynamically) restrict what email addresses can be chosen.

Something like this should work:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class MyAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def clean_email(self, email):
        email = super().clean_email(email)
        if email_has_banned_domain(email):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Your domain is bad.")

        return email
```

Comment: Thanks, I had managed to work this out by furrowing through the terse documentation and questions here on SO - I was about to delete the question, but since you answered, I'll leave it on here - it might help someone else.